# I don't understand why Hibernate is creating 2 sessions?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I've been scratching my head for a while and thought I'd get some help :)

I'm working with a legacy database which I cannot change. I have the following domain:

```
@Entity
public class Institution {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="institution", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Subscription> subscriptions = new ArrayList<Subscription>();
}

@Entity
public class Subscription {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="sub_id", referencedColumnName="ins_sub_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Institution institution;
}
```

For the sake of brevity I have excluded showing the getters/setters. There is no join table.

So;

1) Is the mapping correct? I want a bidirectional association and I want the Institution to be the owner of the relationship.

2) If I load a Institution, create a `new Subscription()` and add the subscription to the `subscriptions` collection...

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add/{institutionId}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitSubscriptionForm(@ModelAttribute SubscriptionForm form) {

    Institution institution = institutionService.getById(form.getInstitutionId());
    Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
    //...set properties on subscripton from data in the form
    subscription.setInstitution(institution);
    institution.getSubscriptions().add(subscription);
    institutionService.saveOrUpdateInstitution(institution);
}
```

...when I save the Institution...

`institutionService.saveOrUpdateInstitution(institution);` just delegates to a DAO which extends HibernateDaoSupport.

...I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:679)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:737)
at com.f1000.dao.hibernate.InstitutionDaoImpl.saveOrUpdate(InstitutionDaoImpl.java:161)
```

I'm using the Spring and am making use of the [OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) and I can't figure out why a second session is created?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in your association,

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="sub_id", referencedColumnName="ins_sub_id")
    private Institution institution;
```

The is a `insertable=false, updatable=false` set on your `institution` inside the `Subscription`. Either you need to remove it or create a new property as below an set that, to the new Subscriptions.

```
private Long institutionId;
```

and replace `subscription.setInstitution(institution);` this by,

```
subscription.setInstitutionId(institution.getId());
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9442483/507864) on more about the `insertable=false, updatable=false` mappings.