# hibernate error: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I am trying to insert a row into a table called Mstrauthorizations. When doing so, I get an error saying  **Could not execute JDBC batch update**. The row is not in the DB - so - I do not see how it could be updating anything at all. The database being used is Oracle. When doing the insert, the keyid is generated with the help of Oracle sequences. My understanding is that the auto-increment of key ids (primary key) is not possible until Oracle 12c. The Mstrauthorizations.java code was generated using Hibernate.

Update: made changes to the Mstrauthorizations.java file and am now getting the following error: **java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY**  I have initialized the attribuetes/fields of the table in the Mstrauthorizations.java file (so no null values would be passed in) but this is not working.

How can I at least see the column that the hibernate command is complaining about? I am trying to do an insert. Why is an update being performed?

**log information**

```
1323 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction  - current autocommit status: false
1327 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener  - generated identifier: 0, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.Assigned
1347 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction  - commit
1348 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - processing flush-time cascades
1349 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - dirty checking collections
1350 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
1350 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
1351 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.pretty.Printer  - listing entities:
1351 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.pretty.Printer  - com.apostx.tables.Mstrauthorizations{employeeid=0, lastlogints=0, reclockts=2007-09-23 10:10:10.0, authorizationsid=0, memo=no value, logonid=joney@mitchell.com, lastname=Mitchell, firstname=Joney, logonpassword=1234567, archived=0, reclockpid=3434, reclockhost=no host, reclocktype=6, active=0, tenantid=5, worktype=0, reclockid=999999}
1368 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher  - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
1373 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into ORAAPPS.MSTRAUTHORIZATIONS (ACTIVE, ARCHIVED, EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTLOGINTS, LASTNAME, LOGONID, LOGONPASSWORD, MEMO, RECLOCKHOST, RECLOCKID, RECLOCKPID, RECLOCKTS, RECLOCKTYPE, TENANTID, WORKTYPE, AUTHORIZATIONSID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
1482 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher  - Executing batch size: 1
1496 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher  - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
1498 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Could not execute JDBC batch update [insert into ORAAPPS.MSTRAUTHORIZATIONS (ACTIVE, ARCHIVED, EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTLOGINTS, LASTNAME, LOGONID, LOGONPASSWORD, MEMO, RECLOCKHOST, RECLOCKID, RECLOCKPID, RECLOCKTS, RECLOCKTYPE, TENANTID, WORKTYPE, AUTHORIZATIONSID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10656)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at com.apostx.hibernate.soverflow.test.TestStack.main(TestStack.java:32)
1498 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000
1498 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

1498 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000
1498 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

1499 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at com.apostx.hibernate.soverflow.test.TestStack.main(TestStack.java:32)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10656)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 8 more
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at com.apostx.hibernate.soverflow.test.TestStack.main(TestStack.java:32)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10656)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 8 more
```

TIA

**Main program - dbconnection test - working**

```
package com.apostx.dbconnection.test;
import java.sql.*;

public class TestDBConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@scar:1527:DSV", "ora787", "Huiu7ti" );
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "select * from MstrAuthorizations";
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);         
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("first col " + rs.getInt(1) + " second col " + rs.getString(2));
                System.out.println( "login id is " + rs.getString("logonid"));
            }
            con.close();        
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println("Database Connection Testing Error : " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Main Program : Not working**

```
package com.apostx.hibernate.test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.apostx.tables.Mstrauthorizations;

public class AddRecord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        // create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().
                configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").
                addAnnotatedClass(Mstrauthorizations.class).
                buildSessionFactory();

        // create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        try {   
            // create object
            System.out.println("about to start the work ....");

            Mstrauthorizations mstr = new Mstrauthorizations();

            BigDecimal tenantid=new BigDecimal(5);
            mstr.setFirstname("Joney"); mstr.setLastname("Mitchell");
            mstr.setTenantid(tenantid);mstr.setLogonid("joney@mitchell.com");
            mstr.setLogonpassword("1234567");mstr.setReclockid(new BigDecimal(999999));
            mstr.setReclockhost("no host");mstr.setReclockpid(new BigDecimal(3434));
            mstr.setReclocktype(new BigDecimal(6));

            // start transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            // save info
            System.out.println("about to save the data ...");
            session.save(mstr);

            // commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("All Saved ...");

        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println("error message is " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }

}
```

**Mstrauthorizations.java**

```
   package com.apostx.tables;

// Generated Jun 22, 2017 9:30:03 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

/**
 * Mstrauthorizations generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "MSTRAUTHORIZATIONS", schema = "ORAAPPS", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "TENANTID", "LOGONID" }),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "TENANTID", "EMPLOYEEID" }) })
public class Mstrauthorizations  {

    private BigDecimal authorizationsid     = new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal tenantid             = new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal employeeid           = new BigDecimal(0);
    private String logonid                  = new String("no value");
    private String logonpassword            = new String("no value");
    private BigDecimal worktype             = new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal lastlogints          = new BigDecimal(0);
    private String memo                     = new String("no value");
    private String firstname                = new String("no value");
    private String lastname                 = new String("no value");
    private BigDecimal active               = new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal archived             = new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal reclocktype          = new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal reclockid            = new BigDecimal(0);
    private String reclockhost              = new String("no value");
    private BigDecimal reclockpid           = new BigDecimal(0);

    private Timestamp reclockts  = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2007-09-23 10:10:10.0");

    public Mstrauthorizations() {
    }

    public Mstrauthorizations(BigDecimal authorizationsid) {
        this.authorizationsid = authorizationsid;
    }

    public Mstrauthorizations(BigDecimal authorizationsid, BigDecimal tenantid,
            BigDecimal employeeid, String logonid, String logonpassword,
            BigDecimal worktype, BigDecimal lastlogints, String memo,
            String firstname, String lastname, BigDecimal active,
            BigDecimal archived, BigDecimal reclocktype, BigDecimal reclockid,
            String reclockhost, BigDecimal reclockpid, Timestamp reclockts) {

        this.authorizationsid = authorizationsid;
        this.tenantid = tenantid;
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
        this.logonid = logonid;
        this.logonpassword = logonpassword;
        this.worktype = worktype;
        this.lastlogints = lastlogints;
        this.memo = memo;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.active = active;
        this.archived = archived;
        this.reclocktype = reclocktype;
        this.reclockid = reclockid;
        this.reclockhost = reclockhost;
        this.reclockpid = reclockpid;
        this.reclockts = reclockts;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AUTHORIZATIONSID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getAuthorizationsid() {
        return this.authorizationsid;
    }

    public void setAuthorizationsid(BigDecimal authorizationsid) {
        this.authorizationsid = authorizationsid;
    }

    @Column(name = "TENANTID", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getTenantid() {
        return this.tenantid;
    }

    public void setTenantid(BigDecimal tenantid) {
        this.tenantid = tenantid;
    }

    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEEID", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getEmployeeid() {
        return this.employeeid;
    }

    public void setEmployeeid(BigDecimal employeeid) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
    }

    @Column(name = "LOGONID", length = 60)
    public String getLogonid() {
        return this.logonid;
    }

    public void setLogonid(String logonid) {
        this.logonid = logonid;
    }

    @Column(name = "LOGONPASSWORD", length = 40)
    public String getLogonpassword() {
        return this.logonpassword;
    }

    public void setLogonpassword(String logonpassword) {
        this.logonpassword = logonpassword;
    }

    @Column(name = "WORKTYPE", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getWorktype() {
        return this.worktype;
    }

    public void setWorktype(BigDecimal worktype) {
        this.worktype = worktype;
    }

    @Column(name = "LASTLOGINTS", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getLastlogints() {
        return this.lastlogints;
    }

    public void setLastlogints(BigDecimal lastlogints) {
        this.lastlogints = lastlogints;
    }

    @Column(name = "MEMO", length = 100)
    public String getMemo() {
        return this.memo;
    }

    public void setMemo(String memo) {
        this.memo = memo;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME", length = 30)
    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME", length = 30)
    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getActive() {
        return this.active;
    }

    public void setActive(BigDecimal active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Column(name = "ARCHIVED", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getArchived() {
        return this.archived;
    }

    public void setArchived(BigDecimal archived) {
        this.archived = archived;
    }

    @Column(name = "RECLOCKTYPE", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getReclocktype() {
        return this.reclocktype;
    }

    public void setReclocktype(BigDecimal reclocktype) {
        this.reclocktype = reclocktype;
    }

    @Column(name = "RECLOCKID", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getReclockid() {
        return this.reclockid;
    }

    public void setReclockid(BigDecimal reclockid) {
        this.reclockid = reclockid;
    }

    @Column(name = "RECLOCKHOST", length = 80)
    public String getReclockhost() {
        return this.reclockhost;
    }

    public void setReclockhost(String reclockhost) {
        this.reclockhost = reclockhost;
    }

    @Column(name = "RECLOCKPID", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getReclockpid() {
        return this.reclockpid;
    }

    public void setReclockpid(BigDecimal reclockpid) {
        this.reclockpid = reclockpid;
    }

    @Column(name = "RECLOCKTS")
    public Serializable getReclockts() {
        return this.reclockts;
    }

    public void setReclockts(Timestamp reclockts) {
        this.reclockts = reclockts;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed when following this:
[Hibernate: Where do insertable = false, updatable = false belong in composite primary key constellations involving foreign keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669883/hibernate-where-do-insertable-false-updatable-false-belong-in-composite-pr)

When data saved to table, ID generated on DB side. Just set "insertable" and "updatable" to false for ID and Timestamp.